# Unable to perform mirror image using Openshift CLI - OC

Tags: openssl, openshift, x509, docker-registry, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to [install  Openshift Container Platform (OCP)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing_vsphere/installing-restricted-networks-installer-provisioned-vsphere.html) in restricted network. However, I've been struggling at the prerequisite step where I have to create a mirror registry to store the data following [this instruction](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing-mirroring-installation-images.html#installing-mirroring-installation-images).

I created docker registry with self-signed certificate authorization and setup variables as illustrated. The error appeared when I ran the following command using OC CLI:

```
sudo oc image mirror -a ${LOCAL_SECRET_JSON} --from-dir=${REMOVABLE_MEDIA_PATH}/mirror "file://openshift/release:${OCP_RELEASE}*" ${LOCAL_REGISTRY}/${LOCAL_REPOSITORY}
```

The error:

```
error: unable to connect to 192.168.100.215:5000/repo: Get "https://192.168.100.215:5000/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "192.168.100.215")
```

I believed that OC didn't trust my certificate but when i tried to add *--certificate-authorty=/certs/domain.crt* (my self-signed certificate) the same error still showed up.

Is there a way to solve this problem, thank you very much!!

ps: I'm new to Redhat Openshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following option to your command in order to skip certificate verification : **--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true**

Comment: thanks, setting **insecure** is a sort of work around even though it isn't recommended..

Comment: yes it's a sort of work around, but since it's a self signed certificate, you can either use the skip-tls-verify , or  you need to add your CA to your system .